# Efficiently copying specific lines to another file (Python 3.3)

Tags: python

How to copy all even lines from one file to a new file in Python?

The even number is just an illustration when I want a very select though substantive number of lines copied from one file to another, but it should be good as an example.

I use this, but it is very inefficient (it takes around 5 minutes):

```
# foo.txt holds 200,000 lines with 300 values
list = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10..... 199996, 199998]
newfile = open(savefile, "w")
with open("foo.txt", "r") as file:
    for i, line in enumerate(file):
        if i in list:
            newfile.write(line)
newfile.close()
```

I would also appreciate it if there's an explanation why this is so slow: reading line by line goes quickly (around 15 seconds), and is also advised by the manual.

**EDIT:** My apologies; I am not looking for specific odd/even examples; it is merely for the effect of how to deal with around 100k out of 200k values in no easy order. Is there no general solution to the I/O problem here other than finding more efficient ways to deal with odd/even? Again apologies for bringing it up.

Comment: What do you mean efficiently? It will have to read the whole file anyway.

Comment: you can remove the `list` and the `list` lookup and replace it with logic, i believe `i % 2 ==0` will give you the same results

Comment: Effectively then? Just a lot quicker. It seems weird it is this slow.

Comment: Does the same hold for appending to a set... will that also be faster?

Comment: Basically, yes. Get used to using `set` anywhere you need to do a lot of lookups from a list of unique elements. Membership testing is `O(1)` in a `set`, as opposed to `O(n)` in a `list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's taking all the time is searching `list`.  In order to figure out whether `i` is in `list`, it has to scan through the entire list to be sure that it's not there.  If you really only care about even numbers, you can simply use `if i % 2 == 0`, but if you have a specific group of line numbers you want, you should use a `set`, which has O(1) membership testing, e.g.

```
keep = {1, 5, 888, 20203}
```

and then

```
if i in keep:
```

Comment: So the set will be a lot quicker than the list?

Comment: @Dualinity: yes.  In order to determine whether 199999 or 200000 is in your list, you have to read through the whole list.  With a set, you almost simply "know".  It's O(N) vs O(1): see [the time complexity](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) page.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen something as amazing as this. Now it took  less than 3 seconds? I can't believe it.

Comment: @Dualinity: if it takes 15 seconds simply to read the file it shouldn't take 3 seconds now, so that surprises me.  [Although 15 seconds seems like a long time to read such a small file.]  That said, you were performing an O(N) operation ~O(N) times, which is going to get you into performance trouble.

Comment: It takes 1 second to just read it in, but the problem is that I need to take specific substrings through a loop to be able to exclude certain areas. Lines that should not be excluded are appended to a list. Should I find a way to do this with a set?

Comment: @Dualinity: IIUC, no; appending to a list is ~O(1), and adding to a set is ~O(1) as well.  Note that you can't "append" to a set because they don't have an ordering.

Comment: I found "update" which does it. Nevertheless, I did not find an increase, as now makes sense by your explanation! Thank you a lot again, also for the link. Might include it in your answer, it's a very good reference.

Answer (score 1):

You're spending tons of time creating and then repeatedly searching (on every line!!!) that monstrous `list`. Just read the first file line by line and skip every other. You can either do this with a toggling flag, or just check if the line number is divisible by two (clearer, in my opinion).

```
for i, line in enumerate(file):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        newfile.write(line)
```

---

**EDIT** in response to your edit: your question is now "how to copy arbitrary lines from a file?" That depends an awful lot on how those arbitrary lines are defined. The answer still is definitely **not** to use a list of "wanted" line numbers, because searching that list takes a long time, and you'll have to search it on every line.

If the goal is essentially to be able to pick random lines from the file, you could use something similar to your current setup, but using `set` instead of `list` to make your lookup fast. A **general-case** proof-of-concept solution might look like this:

```
import random

# Pick 5000 random lines
wanted_lines = set(random.sample(range(200000), 5000)) # Use a set!
for i, line in enumerate(file):
    if i in wanted_lines: # average-case O(1)
        newfile.write(str(line)+'\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your `list` is predefined, and can contain any sequence of possible line indices, not necessarily every Nth line for example.

The first probable bottleneck is that you're doing a O(n) list search (`i in list`) 200000 times. Converting the list to a dictionary should already help:

```
listd = dict.fromkeys(list)
.
.
   # this is O(1) instead of O(n)
   if i in listd:
```

Alternatively, if you know that `list` is sorted, or you can sort it, simply keep track of the next line index:

```
list = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10..... 199996, 199998]
nextidx = 0
newfile = open(savefile, "w")
with open("foo.txt", "r") as file:
    for i, line in enumerate(file):
        if i == list[nextidx]:
            newfile.write(line)
            nextidx += 1
newfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
flag = False
with open("test_async_db_access.py", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        if flag:
            print line
        flag = not flag
```

This avoids having to use the large list

Edit: If it is an arbitrary list of lines you want then use a map {} like DSM's answer this will perform the 'in' in O(1) time instead of O(n).